# How can a discord bot send file with random name to the user?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a question about a discord bot.

Let's suppose that the user wants a file from the server database and that file is downloaded from the internet and also it changes from a time to another. The file name looks like this a bunch of number and letters:

```
5e7fee9c-e12f-430e-9a1c-464adeb9cbc0.html
```

and this file is in a specific directory.

Any help with this?

Comment: you want to download a file off the internet using a bot?

Comment: the file is already downloaded by the bot but, the file name change from time to another so how can I send that file to user. every time the user use the commend the bot download a different file. the problem is what i want to change in the code that the bot know this is the file should he send.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the last downloaded file of a directory, then you should try this :

```
const DIRNAME = './path/to/dir';

function getLastDownloadedFileName() {
    return fs
        .readdirSync(DIRNAME)
        .map(function (fileName) {
            return {
                name: fileName,
                time: fs.statSync(DIRNAME + '/' + fileName).mtime.getTime(),
            };
        })
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.time - b.time;
        })[0].name;
}

/// and then inside the function where you search the file

const lastData = fs.readFileSync(DIRNAME + '/' + getLastDownloadedFileName(), 'utf8');
```